# CRONTAB - Summer/Winder Time-Change

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, time

Since there can be problems with the time change from summer/winter or winter/summer, I wanted to ask how I could solve the problem within the bash script-2?

I think in the winter time it should not come normally to problems since CRON acts here smartly and does not execute CRONS twice, nevertheless I would be grateful here for tips how I could configure the best in both time changes.

```
SUMMER-TIME-CHANGE-GERMANY (RUN AT SAME TIME)
2h - CRONTAB -> Bash-Script 1
3h - CRONTAB -> Bash-Script 2

WINTER-TIME-CHANGE-GERMANY (SHOULD NOT BE A PROBLEM?!)
2h - CRONTAB -> Bash-Script 1
3h - CRONTAB -> Bash-Script 2
```

Comment: IIUC one can set crontab TZ variable. See https://serverfault.com/a/1024611/451558

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

Have the system clock or at least cron run at UTC. UTC has no daylight savings time and you won’t have any issues.

(And like many utilities and tools allow : only convert from UTC to the time zone most relevant to a person in the presentation layer.)

A second consideration:

Cron is a time based scheduler. If you have real job dependencies you can’t really rely on cron to ensure they are met. If batch job B must always start after job A ; simply  use  a single batch job (with some more error checking and handling )

```
#!/bin/sh
/do/job-A
/do/job-B
```

Comment: And how to use utc with cron without using utc as systemwide setting and only for there particular 2 jobs?

Comment: That is what the other comment already links to... https://serverfault.com/questions/791713/what-time-zone-is-a-cron-job-using/1024611#1024611

Comment: Yes but there are other jobs on crontab that should be affected by that, so I just need it for 2 jobs?

Comment: The custom TZ time zone setting effects only the jobs defined below/after that line1 job1 in system TZ schedule ; line two  `CRON_TZ=UTC` ; line 3 job2 running on UTC schedule

Comment: OK thank you, for 2 and 3 h in the night, what need to be set in UTC?